# Add rows to a table in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I can't find a solution to this seemingly easy problem in Pig.

I have a table that looks like:

```
(USA, "big",somevalue1)
(USA, "rich",somevalue2)
(RU, "big",somevalue3)
(BR, "rich",somevalue4)
(BR, "rich",somevalue5)
```

As an output I want

```
(USA, "big",somevalue1)
(USA, "rich",somevalue2)
(RU, "big",somevalue3)
(RU, "rich",0)
(BR, "rich",somevalue4)
(BR, "rich",somevalue5)
(BR, "big",0)
```

i.e add rows so that each country shares the same "information" with regard to the second column, even if it means filling with zero unknown values.

**EDIT**

Here's the solution I came up with

```
USA "big"   1
USA "rich"  2
RU  "big"   3
BR  "rich"  4
BR  "rich"  5
```

(input example.txt)

```
A = LOAD 'example.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (cty: chararray, prop:chararray, value: int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE cty;
B = DISTINCT B;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE prop;
C = DISTINCT C;
D = CROSS B, C;

X = JOIN D BY (cty,prop) LEFT, A BY (cty,prop) using 'replicated';
K = FOREACH X GENERATE 
                B::cty AS cty,
                C::prop AS prop,
                (value is NULL ? 0 : value);
DUMP K;
```

Which gives as expected:

```
(USA,"rich",2)
(USA,"big",1)
(RU,"rich",0)
(RU,"big",3)
(BR,"rich",4)
(BR,"rich",5)
(BR,"big",0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the easiest way would be to group by the first field,  and then foreach group,  send the related bag into your own UDF that will iterate through the tuples in the bag,  and will return a new bag with the existing tuples + the default tuple if needed.

In order to create a list of required values for the second field ("utility_bag"), you can use distinct and group by ALL.

Here is how your script should look like:

```
input_data = LOAD 'input.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') 
               AS (country:chararray, f2:chararray, somevalue:chararray);

only_second_field = FOREACH input_data GENERATE f2;
distinct_list = DISTINCT only_second_field;
utility_bag = GROUP distinct_list ALL;

grouped = FOREACH (GROUP input_data BY country) 
     GENERATE group, CustomUDF(input_data, utility_bag.distinct_list) AS enhancedBag;

result = FOREACH grouped GENERATE flatten(enhancedBag);
```

Your custom UDF should get 2 parameters:

1. Bag with the original schema: {(country:chararray, f2:chararray, somevalue:chararray)}
2. Bag with schema: {(f2: chararray)}
   For example: {(big),(rich),(lonely)}

   - You can play with the bag a bit in order to eliminate the tuples and leave only values.

Regarding the solution that you came up with, it is good, but it is not very efficient due to the usage of CROSS and JOIN operations, which are resulting with extra MapReduce jobs. 
You can learn about this subject in this series on when to avoid using CROSS in Pig: http://blog.mortardata.com/post/74952451884/why-did-the-pig-cross-the-join-part-4
Hope it will help.

Comment: I do not know the default tuple in advance. In my example I don't know that the set { "big" ,"rich"} must appear for each country. This set could have been bigger like  { "big" ,"rich", "oil"}. I need first to isolate the "maximal" set...

Comment: I didn't know that this is an unlimited list of values and not only "big" and "rich". So I edited my answer with a detailed solution to your problem. hope it will do the job.